# Customize JSON Reporter to show Scraped Data - WebdriverIO

Tags: javascript, json, appium, webdriver-io

I am scraping an android app using WDIO and APPIUM. I did some scraping and stored the data in an array. Now i want to output the array data to a .json file automatically (instead of copy pasting it from console). I came across JSON reporter for WDIO, but the website doesn't provide any clear info about how i can customize the Test result. I also tried return the array into my afterTest hooks but no luck.

```
reporters: [
  'dot',
  ['json',{
      outputDir: './Results'
  }]
],
```

Please help !

Answer (score 0):

Instead of customizing the reporter. I used the node js fs module to saved my scraped data after a sucessfull test. You can save in any format but make sure you convert the scraped to desired format before saving. Thank you